# I can't connect my Flask Gunicorn app with nginx

Tags: python-3.x, linux, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have made a Flask Gunicorn Application, but I can't connect it with nginx.
I am using the latest version of nginx. I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) And done everything as shown there.

I programmed a completely empty flask app, which worked. But as soon as I connect my real app, I always get the error 502 Bad Gateway.

**Can anyone help me?**

*(Sorry for my bad english skills)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. I set flask to use https, but nginx was still set to http